# esper thread pools with contexts and subscriber dispatch order

Tags: esper

if the Esper application works with contexts, can you use thread pool inbound? enabling it i have had some errors with unique keys. On the other hand, if the subscriber dispatch order is important, is it possible to use thread pool outbound?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes thread pool inbound can be used as always. It may be better if you can post the unique key exception or make sure you are not violating unique key indexes or declare the index non-unique. 
For the subscribers with thread pool outbound there is no way that there can be a guarantee of ordering, I think.